# The concept of a linear map being self-adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

In class, we were told:

> let V be a finite dimensional inner product space. A linear map $T: V \to V$ is self if $T = T^*$

Later, we were told:

> let V be a finite dimensional real inner prod. space. Let $T: V \to V$ be a LM then T has an orthonormal eigenbasis iff T is self-adjoint

However (my professor has not done any proofs lately), I am a bit confused. Suppose you have a non-orthonormal eigenbasis, and you have a diagonal standard matrix $D$.

Would $D^*$ not be equal to $D$, so the condition of the eigenbasis being orthonormal is violated?

What am I missing? Proof-based insight is appreciated.

Comment: **HINT**: What is $(PDP^{-1})^*$?

Comment: From my understanding, $(PDP^{-1})^* = (P^{-1})^*(PD)^* = (P^{-1})^*D^*P^*$.

Comment: If $D$ is diagonal, then how are you proposing that its eigenbasis is not orthonormal?

Comment: I do not quite understand @AlkaKadri . From my understanding, D can be diagonal with any eigenbasis. It is not necessary for the eigenbasis to be orthonormal

Comment: So if $P^*\ne P^{-1}$, will $A^* = (PDP^{-1})^* = A$?

Comment: Could you please give more of a hint @TedShifrin ? I see that $A = PDP^{-1}$ and $A^* = (P^{-1})^*D^*P^*$. If $P^* = P^{-1}$ then we have $A = PDP^{-1}$ and $A^* = PD^*P^* = P(PD)^*$ ... so I am not seeing it.

Comment: No, the eigenbasis of a diagonal matrix $D$ must certainly be orthonormal. In fact, the vectors $e_i = (0, \dots, 1, \dots, 0)$ with a one in the $i$-th entry are all eigenvectors.

Comment: @user129393192 I think you're getting confused between the concepts of "diagonal" and "diagonalizable". A diagonalizable operator does not necessarily have an orthonormal eigenbasis. A diagonal matrix (or an operator with a diagonal standard matrix) does

Comment: I thought you have a diagonal matrix even if the eigenbasis is not orthonormal @BenGrossmann?

Comment: @user129393192 That is not correct

Comment: Let’s say you have two eigenvalues 2 and 1, with geometric multiplicity 2 and 1. Is it not possibly to form a basis from them that is not linearly independent @BenGrossmann?

Comment: @user129393192 I don't understand your question. In any case, I stand by my earlier point that you're getting confused between the idea of a "diagonalizable" transformation and a "diagonal" matrix.

Comment: I'm just confused because I thought you are "diagonalizable" if you have a basis where the standard matrix is diagonal, and you are diagonal if you have a basis of eigenvectors (which are not necessarily orthogonal)